# ASP.NET Core - Using multiple authentication methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to find a way to have multiple possibilities to authenticate against a controller method.
The current way to authenticate against the API is through NTLM, because until now it was only possible to call the API from a windows machine.
Now I also want to reach the API from a Linux server and have to use a different authentication method than NTLM (for example: use an API Key).

My question is: How can I register multiple methods for authentication and allow the request if at least one of these is successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use [multiple authentication schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x#use-multiple-authentication-schemes). I've used this to use both cookies and JWT together in same app. When multiple are configured, the Authorize attribute can specify which to use, for example:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer,Cookies")]
```

Comment: But does this allow the call to pass if one of the two authentication options is met or only if all are met?

Comment: It's an "or" and passes if either of the methods succeed. I use this to authenticate web users with a cookie and API client requests with JWT.